# Number function is considering -0 as 0 in javascript

Tags: javascript

Lets say I have a string.

```
const myStr = "-0";
```

I want to check the sign of this numeric string. I am doing in this way

```
Math.sign(Number(myStr)) === -1 || Math.sign(Number(myStr)) === -0
```

But the number function is converting -0 as 0 because of that Math.sign(Number(myStr)) === -0 is giving false. I want to why Number() is behaving like this and is there any way so that the sign of numeric string can be preserved after the converting to number.

Comment: What do you expect to happen? `-0` is the same as `0`!

Comment: Is there a meaningful difference between `0` and `-0`? `-0 === 0` is `true` in Firefox.

Comment: `Number("-0")` is `-0` and `Math.sign(Number("-0")) === -0` is `true` for me, where are you running this?

Comment: Which browser / runtime?

Comment: @AlexK. is correct  [here is an example](https://jsbin.com/kuzucuvamo/1/edit?js,console)

Comment: Can you edit the question and shape your code into a runnable snippet that illustrates the issue? I tried doing so but it was working for me. It's possible that the issue lies somewhere else (for instance, `myStr` containing a different value that you think).